# How can you build a MapReduce pipeline in RavenDB?

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have a theoretical question about RavenDB - is it possible to build a MapReduce pipeline?

So for instance, let's say I have MapReduce output Y from Index 1 and I use that output for some queries, but I need to run another MapReduce operation on Y in order to get some lower-level statistics.

Is it possible for me to write Index 2 which can further MapReduce the output from Index 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaronontheweb,
Not at the moment, no.
It is a feature that you could handle using Indexed Properties bundle in 1.2

Comment: Thanks, Ayende. Really appreciate the answer! So I see the Bundle here https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/tree/master/Bundles/Raven.Bundles.IndexedProperties - are there any examples on how to use it?